# PCA statistical units

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, units

I have a school project where I'm required to use a factor analysis. I chose this [dataset](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/police-killings) from **FiveThirtyEight** about police killings. I want to characterize the places where people have been killed so I decided to group the data by cities, compute some summary statistics (median income, poverty rate etc) and perform a PCA.

Can I perform my exploratory data analysis on the original data where the statistical units are the people killed and then use the pca on the cities, hence changing the statistical units? I'm asking this because we are required to define the statistical units in the introduction.

And if it is possible or not, is there a justification for doing so? From a statistical standpoint.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of pre-processing on the data to scale the various variables? If you are scaling to unit variance, then my answer discusses that and this also applies to any multiplicative scaling. If you are doing some other type of pre-processing let me know and I can update the answer more tuned to that.

Comment: I don't understand in what sense you might "use" a PCA on victims in analysing data for cities. There is much literature on problems linking two scales like that.  One key term is "ecological fallacy". But that is largely a matter of what social scientific or policy inferences are possible as well as a statistical question.

Comment: @ReneBt thanks for your help. I actually wanted to know if it was possible to look at two different populations in my study. I am interested in victims and states here. I ask because I need to define the population that the study is looking at

Comment: @NickCox I don't want to perform the PCA on victims but rather on the states. Thanks for raising this point

Comment: As in my case, it's optimistic to assume that people will click on your link and study what is said there, let alone think for themselves about how to analyse the data. I don't think the question is clear enough about exactly what you intend and what you want by way of an answer.

Comment: Just finally clicked what you mean by units after re-reading Nick's comments below my answer. I would advise rewording your question and being more explicit about what you want to do and why as I can't get a picture of it even if I substitute something like 'group' for where you use 'unit'.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, English not being my native language, I used the term **"unit"** based on this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_unit) article. What is the correct term to use? And what correction would you suggest to my question?
Basically, I want to know if it is possible to study 2 distinct populations in the same study. The first one (here the victims) in my exploratory analysis to see some of their characteristics, and use the second one (here the states) to do a PCA to extract information on the locations of these killings.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PC eigenvectors are dimensionless weights and do not themselves imply any change in units in individual variables when multiplied by the sample data.

The PC scores are the sum of these multiplications across each variable. This means that if the units of all variables are identical then the units of the scores will be those of the variables.

If the units of the variable differ then things get tricky. Multiplicative interactions between different units create a new unit, but additive ones do not. Dividing distance (km) by time (h) gives us speed (km h$^{-1}$) but adding distance and time doesn't give a physically meaningful unit. To be able to sum different variables to a physically meaningful unit requires transformation to a common scale.

A common form of pre-processing is scaling to unit variance, which involves dividing each unit by its standard deviation. The units of standard deviation are identical to that of the individual values and the result of the division is cancelling of the units to give a dimensionless number of arbitrary units.

To identify the units of the output you need to determine the units of the variables as these are input into the actual PCA.

Comment: I think the OP is using units quite differently, to refer to whatever defines distinct observations (cases, records) in each dataset, namely victims or cities.

Comment: @NickCox that's indeed what I meant. I'm sorry for not being clear enough.